# Unity3D Quaternion libGDX equivalent

Tags: java, 3d, unity-game-engine, libgdx

## Quaternion.Lerp

static Quaternion Lerp(Quaternion from, Quaternion to, float t);

Description:
Interpolates between from and to by t and normalizes the result afterwards.
This is faster than Slerp but looks worse if the rotations are far apart.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform from;
    public Transform to;
    public float speed = 0.1F;
    void Update() {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(from.rotation, to.rotation, Time.time * speed);
    }
}
```

Could you write down a quivalent in libGDX please? I'm trying to do long time and without success.

Comment: From the description, that sounds like nlerp. To get it, linearly interpolate each of the components of the quaternion, and then normalize it.

Answer (score 1):

libGDX has slerp method:

slerp(Quaternion[] q)
Spherical linearly interpolates multiple quaternions and stores the result in this Quaternion.

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Quaternion.html

Comment: Yes but I need equivalent for: transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(from.rotation, to.rotation, Time.time * speed); exaclty like it is. only for LibGDX.